# Use filebeat to ship XML data which does not have newline between the elements

Tags: wcf, elasticsearch, logstash, trace, filebeat

I have a set of log files (WCF trace files) in XML that does not have a newline between the log elements. Instead, there is a start tag/end tag. 
Example:

```
<E2ETraceEvent><log data/></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent><logdata/></E2ETraceEvent>
```

I would like to store the E2ETraceEvents separately in ES.

The file is appended to by the running WCF service. Is it possible to ship this via filebeat to logstash? Can filebeat match on tags? Or do filebeat require a newline to be present? Any other options?

Comment: Have you successfully send WCF logs to ES?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We gave it up, and added more logging using log4net.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to override the write methods in the System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener class and use your new class as the trace listener.

```
public class TestPrettyPrint : System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener
{
    public TestPrettyPrint(Stream stream) : base(stream) { }
    public TestPrettyPrint(string filename) : base(filename) { }
    public TestPrettyPrint(TextWriter tw) : base(tw) { }
    public TestPrettyPrint(Stream stream, string filename) : base(stream, filename) { }
    public TestPrettyPrint(string filename, string name) : base(filename, name) { }
    public TestPrettyPrint(TextWriter tw, string name) : base(tw, name) { }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        message = PrettyPrintMessage(message);
        base.Write(message);
    }

    public override void Write(string message, string category)
    {
        message = PrettyPrintMessage(message);
        base.Write(message, category);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        message = PrettyPrintMessage(message);
        base.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message, string category)
    {
        message = PrettyPrintMessage(message);
        base.WriteLine(message, category);
    }

    private string PrettyPrintMessage(string messageToPP)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(messageToPP);
            return doc.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return messageToPP;
        }
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging

Then replace System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener with MyNamespace.TestPrettyPrint when setting up the trace listener in your web.config.

You can then setup a multiline prospector in filebeat to send the information to logstash.

Comment: Excellent idea, we'll look into this the next time we touch our crusty, old WCF service.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature for filtering or grok functionalitiy and you can look this following discussions:

- https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/679#issuecomment-227654380
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/grok-pattern-with-multiline-management-in-filebeat/41903

In this case, there are some options for you,

First, you can forward logs from multiple server to one logstash with multiple filebeat. And this structure provide you to be able to filter and manipulate your logs. Check below links:

- https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2015/12/10/configuring-logstash-with-filebeat/
- http://www.mattkimber.co.uk/shipping-logs-to-logstash-with-filebeat/
- https://github.com/hkulekci/elasticsearch-workshop

Second, you can use `_ingest` API of Elasticsearch v5.x. Check the Elasticsearch documentation:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/configuring-ingest-node.html

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate the options provided!